# How to use multi colors in drawtext FFmpeg

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, drawtext

How can i use multi colors in drawtext ffmpeg. for example text='NATIONAL PARK' , now i want 'NATIONAL' in blue and 'PARK' in red.

How  can i do that in FFmpeg.

Comment: You'll need multiple drawtext filters in a chain.

Comment: Or use [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles).

Comment: @Mulvya tried multiple drawtext , then it becomes difficult to align text and space in between words, searching for something more convenient way.

Comment: True. It *may* be possible to do this with the fontcolor_expr option. Will have to test.

Comment: Is there any way in fontcolor_expr to define multi color based on text or index of letter in the text ? please give me if you know any link or article more about fontcolor_expr .

Comment: have you found a solution in the end?

Comment: Not yet, still using multiple drawtext filters

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i inp.jpg \
    -vf "drawtext=text='BLUE':fontcolor=blue:fontsize=20:x=10:y=10:,  drawtext=text='RED':fontcolor=red:fontsize=20:x=10+60+10:y=10:" \
    -y out.jpg
```

;-)

Comment: how would you make the spacing work for any length of text?

Comment: I am afraid you can't make it work for any length of text because you'd have to calculate the width for each word which is mostly complex